# What does General Ardmore mean by "immune response"?

Tags: avatar-the-way-of-water

In *Avatar: The Way of Water*, General Ardmore tells Miles Quaritch:

> we believe your blue team will be perceived as indigenous and will not trigger the immune response.

What is the "immune response" she is talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

She meant the incident from the end of the first movie, where every animal in the region came and joined the Na'vi in attacking humans, in the end finally defeating them and forcing them to leave Pandora. It certainly looked like the whole planet rebelled against human invaders, which is not that dissimilar to immune response.